# Implement UDP communication without blocking UI

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, async-await, udp, threadpool

I currently have a partly synchronous (poor) implementation of UDP communication between my android App and a hardware which is broadcasting UDP packets. The App continuously polls the hardware for status information which then is used to update the UI. The App also has various screens, each requesting (only when user switches screens, not continuous) a different set of configuration information. The user can also make changes to the configurations and load them to the hardware. All this while, the status updates keeps running in the background. I am looking for a solution best suited to my scenario.

Here is what I have done so far (simplified to make it more readable)

```
void InitializeUDP()
{
    udpClient = new UdpClient(15001);
    sender = default(IPEndPoint);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => UDP_StatusCommunicator());

    udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
    udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 500;
}

void UDP_StatusCommunicator()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (update_flag)
                {                    
                    try
                    {
                        sent_packet = FrameGenerator(frame_Queue[screen], true); //Creates UDP Packet                        
                        //CheckQuery(sent_packet);
                        udpClient.Send(sent_packet, sent_packet.Length,"192.168.4.255", 15000);
                        received_packet = udpClient.Receive(ref sender);
                        //CheckResponse(received_packet);
                        RunOnUiThread(() =>
                            {
                                Update_UI(received_packet);
                            });                        
                    }
                    catch (SocketException e)
                    {
                        Console.Writeline("Socket Timeout: " + e);
                    }
                }                
                Thread.Sleep(update_delay);
            }
        }

void UDPReadWrite(int screen, bool reading)
        {
            SelectFunctionQueue(screen);  //Select the frames according to the screen selected
            //CheckQueue(frame_Queue);

            for (int i = 0; i < frame_Queue.Length; i++)
            {
                    try
                    {
                        sent_packet = FrameGenerator(frame_Queue[i], reading);
                        //CheckQuery(sent_packet);
                        udpClient.Send(sent_packet, sent_packet.Length, "192.168.4.255", 15000);
                        received_packet = udpClient.Receive(ref sender);
                        //CheckResponse(received_packet);
                        if (sent_packet[2] == received_packet[2])  //Verify correct packet received
                        {
                            Update_UI(received_packet);                        
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            i--;                   //retry
                        }
                    }
                    catch (SocketException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Socket Timeout: " e);
                        i--;
                    }
                }                
            }
        }

void Switch_Screen(int new_screen)
        {
            update_flag = false;
            UDPReadWrite(new_screen, true)
            update_flag = true;
        }

void User_Config_Write(int screen, byte[] data)
        {
            update_flag = false;
            Update_Payload(data);
            UDPReadWrite(screen, false)
            update_flag = true;
        }
```

As you would have clearly noticed, this is a very flawed implementation. I keep running into issues like UI freeze, same socket usage being attempted by two threads simultaneously, stuck while waiting for packets. I have tried to use 'async await' but I am not implementing it correctly resulting in race conditions and what not. Any help would be appreciated

**Update : After some research and testing I have found the below to be working satisfactorily. However, I would appreciate if someone could just verify whether it has been done correctly**

```
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
UdpClient r_UdpClient = new UdpClient(15001);
IPEndPoint sender = default(IPEndPoint);
ManualResetEventSlim receive = new ManualResetEventSlim(true);
Task.Run(() => UDP_Transmit());

async void UDP_Transmit()
        {
            byte[] frame;
            SelectFrameQueue(selector);
            udpClient = new UdpClient(15001);
            udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
            udpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(UDP_Receive), udpClient);
            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < frame_Queue.Length; i++)
                {                    
                        frame = FrameGenerator(frame_Queue[i]);  //Generates Frames
                        try
                        {
                            udpClient.Send(frame, frame.Length, "192.168.4.255", 15000);
                        }
                        catch (SocketException)
                        {
                            Log.Debug("Error", "Socket Exception");
                        }

                        if(!receive.Wait(10000))   //Receive Timeout
                        {
                            RunOnUiThread(() =>
                            {
                                ShowToast("Connection Timeout. Please check device");
                            });
                        };
                        await Task.Delay(update_delay);    //To release pressure from H/W
                        receive.Reset();                        
                }                             
            }
        }

void UDP_Receive(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            receive.Set();
            r_UdpClient = result.AsyncState as UdpClient;
            data = r_UdpClient.EndReceive(result, ref sender);
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {               
                Update_UI(data);                            
            });
            r_UdpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(UDP_Receive), r_UdpClient);            
        }
```

Comment: _"I have tried to use 'async await'"_ -- I don't see anything in the code you posted that uses `await`. The solution to not blocking the UI is to use asynchronous I/O to handle the socket. There are lots of options, but async/await is the modern idiom. So, provide a good [mcve] showing your attempt to use async/await, explain exactly what that code does, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you have tried and need help with. Note that there are countless resources for examples of how to do network I/O asynchronously, here and elsewhere on the web.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have used AsyncCallback to improve my code (updated) and my UI is more responsive. But there are still some instances where the UI doesn't respond to touch or is getting blocked. Do you see an error in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the intent of this code is:

```
void InitializeUDP()
{
    udpClient = new UdpClient(15001);
    sender = default(IPEndPoint);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => UDP_StatusCommunicator());

    udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
    udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 500;
}
```

but it is not guaranteed that

```
    udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
    udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 500;
```

is executed before `UDP_StatusCommunicator()`.

For client UIs like Xamarin `Task.Run` can be a good option over `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.

You might want to take a look at [Dataflow (Task Parallel Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), in particular to the [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) to replace your queue.

You might also want to consider using [Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) to report updates to the UI or using [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) to subscribe to updates from the UI.